# Loading text file containing both float and string using numpy.loadtxt

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I have a text file, `data.txt`, which contains:

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.8,2.7,4.1,1.0,Iris-versicolor
6.2,2.2,4.5,1.5,Iris-versicolor
6.4,3.1,5.5,1.8,Iris-virginica
6.0,3.0,4.8,1.8,Iris-virginica
```

How do I load this data using `numpy.loadtxt()` so that I get a NumPy array after loading such as `[['5.1' '3.5' '1.4' '0.2' 'Iris-setosa'] ['4.9' '3.0' '1.4' '0.2' 'Iris-setosa'] ...]`?

I tried

```
np.loadtxt(open("data.txt"), 'r',
           dtype={
               'names': (
                   'sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length',
                   'petal width', 'label'),
               'formats': (
                   np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, np.str)},
           delimiter= ',', skiprows=0)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you use [np.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), you could specify `dtype=None`, which will tell `genfromtxt` to intelligently guess the dtype of each column. Most conveniently, it relieves you of the burder of specifying the number of bytes required for the string column. (Omitting the number of bytes, by specifying e.g. `np.str`, does not work.)

```
In [58]: np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=('sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'label'))
Out[58]: 
array([(5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
       (4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'Iris-setosa'),
       (5.8, 2.7, 4.1, 1.0, 'Iris-versicolor'),
       (6.2, 2.2, 4.5, 1.5, 'Iris-versicolor'),
       (6.4, 3.1, 5.5, 1.8, 'Iris-virginica'),
       (6.0, 3.0, 4.8, 1.8, 'Iris-virginica')], 
      dtype=[('sepal_length', '<f8'), ('sepal_width', '<f8'), ('petal_length', '<f8'), ('petal_width', '<f8'), ('label', 'S15')])
```

---

If you do want to use `np.loadtxt`, then to fix your code with minimal changes, you could use:

```
np.loadtxt("data.txt",
   dtype={'names': ('sepal length', 'sepal width', 'petal length', 'petal width', 'label'),
          'formats': (np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float, '|S15')},
   delimiter=',', skiprows=0)
```

The main difference is simply changing `np.str` to `|S15` (a 15-byte string).

Also note that 
`open("data.txt"), 'r'` should be `open("data.txt", 'r')`. But since `np.loadtxt` can accept a filename, you don't really need to use `open` at all.

Comment: When I try this my strings are read in as byte literals, such as b'ADT1_YEAST'. Do I have to cast them manually or is there a way to get it to read in strings like your example?

Comment: @mattgabor: If you change `dtype=None` to `dtype=['<f8','<f8','<f8','<f8','U15']` then `np.genfromtxt` will load the last column as `str`s instead of `byte`s.

Comment: For me loadtxt() did not work when text file included '#'. It returned wrong number of columns for some reason. I have replaced '#' with other character then using line.replace('#',' ')

Comment: @vlad: `genfromtxt` and `loadtxt` have a `comments` parameter which is set to `'#'` by default. All characters after the comment character are discarded. That is probably why the parser was finding the wrong number of columns. You might be able to avoid the problem by setting `comments` to something other than `'#'`.

Answer (score 28):

It seems that keeping the numbers and text together has been causing you so much trouble - if you end up deciding to separate them, my workaround is:

```
values = np.loadtxt('data', delimiter=',', usecols=[0,1,2,3])
labels = np.loadtxt('data', delimiter=',', usecols=[4])
```

Comment: For the labels, I think you need to add `dtype=np.str` to make it work. Otherwise, you will get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Iris-setosa` or something similar.

Comment: np.genfromtxt is more robust in general, and has saved me a great deal of heartache since I originally answered this question

Comment: And consider looking into pandas. You'll never use .loadtxt or .genfromtxt again!