# Selecting a dataframe column without dropping the label

Tags: python, pandas

How do I select a dataframe column, df['col'], without dropping the name of the column?

```
df
index colname col1 col2 col3
  1             0    1    2
  2             3    4    5
  3             6    7    8
  4             9   10   11
```

Desired output:

```
df['col1']
index colname col1 
  1             0   
  2             3    
  3             6    
  4             9
```

**Edit:** as correctly answered, df[['col1']] does the job... Now a bit more tricky. What if the columns are multiindexed?

```
df    grpname A            B            ...  Z
index colname cA1 ... cAN  cB1 ... cBN  ...  cZ1 ... cZN
  1           a11 ... a1N  b11 ... b1N  ...  z11 ... z1N
  2           a21 ... a2N  b21 ... b2N  ...  z21 ... z2N
  3           a31 ... a3N  b31 ... b3N  ...  z31 ... z3N
  4           a41 ... a4N  b41 ... b4N  ...  z41 ... z4N
```

I want to get

```
df    grpname A            
index colname cA1 cA2  
  1           a11 a12 
  2           a21 a22 
  3           a31 a32  
  4           a41 a42
```

Looks like .xs() only allows me to retrieve a certain column, namely df.xs( ('A', 'cAi'), level=('grpname','colname'), axis=1, drop_level=False) ), and df[['A']]['cA1':'cAi'] doesn't work either?

Comment: Does `df[['col']]` not do what you desire?

Comment: df[['col']] should still work I don't understand what you desire exactly, can you post code that reproduces the data and the output

Comment: Now it's maybe more clear. I want to get the 'A' group with only two of the 'cols' without dropping the labels.

Comment: please post the code that reproduces the data and the groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single column selection then `df['col']` will return a series, if you want to keep the column name then you need to double subscript which will return a dataframe:

```
In [2]:

import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False)
import io
temp = """index col1 col2 col3
  1             0    1    2
  2             3    4    5
  3             6    7    8
  4             9   10   11"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+',index_col=[0])
df
Out[2]:
       col1  col2  col3
index                  
1         0     1     2
2         3     4     5
3         6     7     8
4         9    10    11
In [4]:

df[['col1']]
Out[4]:
       col1
index      
1         0
2         3
3         6
4         9
```

contrast this with:

```
In [5]:

df['col1']
Out[5]:
index
1        0
2        3
3        6
4        9
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**
As @joris has pointed out you can see that the name is displayed at the bottom of the output, the name isn't lost as such just a different output

Comment: Note that the column name is not 'lost', the difference is just in the representation. The Series still has the name, but in the representation, this is at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about it... Can you check the edit and see if you can answer this for multiindexed cols?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it if you are sure of the space taken by each column.
Here is [the example ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546349/loading-text-file-containing-both-float-and-string-using-numpy-loadtxt)

```
np.loadtxt("df.txt",
    dtype={
        'names': ('index', 'colname', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'),
        'formats': (np.float, np.string, np.float, np.float, np.float)},
        delimiter= ' ', skiprows=1)
```

Comment: This is not about reading a file, but about indexing an existing dataframe