# python numpy valueError

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a csv file with lines like this:

```
"Time","V1" ,"V2","Class"
  0   , 0.65, 0.45, "0"
```

I try to create a numpy array this way:

```
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("creditcard.csv", delimiter="," , skiprows=1 )
```

But i've got this exception:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: b'"0"'
```

Can you tell me how can I load the csv without replacing all " character in the file?

Thank you!

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546349/loading-text-file-containing-both-float-and-string-using-numpy-loadtxt

Comment: yes, it's seems like.. this is the solution.. :)

Comment: Is that quoted column supposed to loaded as a string, or as an unquoted number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading text file containing both float and string using numpy.loadtxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546349/loading-text-file-containing-both-float-and-string-using-numpy-loadtxt)