# How can I create a neural network with Keras that trains from tabular data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm relatively new to Python, so please forgive the ignorance. I have tabular data that looks like:

```
Type,Name,Age,Breed1,Breed2,Gender,Color1,Color2,Color3,MaturitySize,FurLength,Vaccinated,Dewormed,Sterilized,Health,Quantity,Fee,State,RescuerID,VideoAmt,Description,PetID,PhotoAmt,AdoptionSpeed
2,Nibble,3,299,0,1,1,7,0,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,100,41326,8480853f516546f6cf33aa88cd76c379,0,Nibble is a 3+ month old ball of cuteness. He is energetic and playful. I rescued a couple of cats a few months ago but could not get them neutered in time as the clinic was fully scheduled. The result was this little kitty. I do not have enough space and funds to care for more cats in my household. Looking for responsible people to take over Nibble's care.,86e1089a3,1.0,2
2,No Name Yet,1,265,0,1,1,2,0,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,0,41401,3082c7125d8fb66f7dd4bff4192c8b14,0,I just found it alone yesterday near my apartment. It was shaking so I had to bring it home to provide temporary care.,6296e909a,2.0,0
1,Brisco,1,307,0,1,2,7,0,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,0,41326,fa90fa5b1ee11c86938398b60abc32cb,0,"Their pregnant mother was dumped by her irresponsible owner at the roadside near some shops in Subang Jaya. Gave birth to them at the roadside. They are all healthy and adorable puppies. Already dewormed, vaccinated and ready to go to a home. No tying or caging for long hours as guard dogs. However, it is acceptable to cage or tie for precautionary purposes. Interested to adopt pls call me.",3422e4906,7.0,3
1,Miko,4,307,0,2,1,2,0,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,150,41401,9238e4f44c71a75282e62f7136c6b240,0,"Good guard dog, very alert, active, obedience waiting for her good master, plz call or sms for more details if you really get interested, thanks!!",5842f1ff5,8.0,2
```

I have a ton of training data and I want to create a neural network to predict the last value `AdoptionSpeed`.

Here's what I have using `keras` so far:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("data/train.csv", delimiter=",")

X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.read_csv('data/train.csv')`? It is a much more flexible file handler specially when it comes to a dataset with mixed column types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) of numpy loadtxt is `float`.  Instead use:

```
dataset = np.loadtxt("data/train.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=np.str)
```

Comment: Some of the values are floats, however. So how would I handle that?

Comment: @Shamoon looks like there is a nicer way to read from numpy that automatically guess the dtype, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546349/loading-text-file-containing-both-float-and-string-using-numpy-loadtxt, alternatively you can use `np.float('value')` while accessing each float values

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `csv` file that you are passing to `np.loadtxt` funnction, some of the columns are not having `float` type of data. Few columns are strings. So, while loading the `csv` file,  default datatype for conversion is float for `np.loadtxt` function. This is the reason for the error. Best way to overcome is by using python `readlines` function for a file and iterate over all the lines.

Generally, neural network expects inputs to be in the form of numbers. For converting the `string` to `float` values, you can use something like `word2vec` or `Tf-Idf` and their embedding alternatives.

As you want predict the `Adoptionspeed`, you can treat this problem as a regression problem.