# how can we convert string to float?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

hi im trying to execute a cell in jupyter notebook which consists of txt file I did something like this:

```
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("C:/Users/jayjay/learning/try.txt", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X=dataset[:100,2:4]
Y=dataset[:100,4]
```

when im trying to run this I get this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-d2d2260af43e> in <module>
----> 1 dataset = numpy.loadtxt("C:/Users/jayjay/learning/try.txt", delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
      2 # split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
      3 X=dataset[:100,2:4]
      4 Y=dataset[:100,4]


    ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'not 1'
```

I have a data which is similar to this in try.txt:

```
135,10,125,10,1
230,16,214,19,not 1
226,16,210,19,1
231,16,215,19,not 1
205,16,189,17,not 1
```

how do I solve this error? im a self learning newbie. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: which line is giving error. Because in above line you are not converting string to float.

Comment: `not 1` causes the error ; convert attributes from nominal to numeric

Comment: 1st line is giving error

Comment: yes yes, I understood that not 1 causes the error. how do I resolve it?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: if it contains only 2 labels, make it 0

Comment: you mean? changing "not 1" to 0. I considered that firstly because it would make my work easy. but  by making it little complex. I thought I could learn a new thing.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546349/loading-text-file-containing-both-float-and-string-using-numpy-loadtxt

Comment: np.genfromtxt('sample.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=None)

Comment: @Bhaskar tried the solution in the link which you provided..new error returns which is -----IndexError: too many indices for array------on the line ----> 4 X=dataset[:100,2:4]

Comment: yeah you should access it like this X = dataset[:100][1:2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice that you provided a file sample:

```
In [1]: txt="""135,10,125,10,1 
   ...: 230,16,214,19,not 1 
   ...: 226,16,210,19,1 
   ...: 231,16,215,19,not 1 
   ...: 205,16,189,17,not 1"""
```

`loadtxt` accepts a list of strings inplace of a file:

```
In [2]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',')                           
...
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'not 1'
```

It tries to return a float array, but the `not 1` string gives problems:

`genfromtxt` is similar, but gives `nan` when it can create the float:

```
In [3]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',')                        
Out[3]: 
array([[135.,  10., 125.,  10.,   1.],
       [230.,  16., 214.,  19.,  nan],
       [226.,  16., 210.,  19.,   1.],
       [231.,  16., 215.,  19.,  nan],
       [205.,  16., 189.,  17.,  nan]])
```

You could  skip the problem column:

```
In [4]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',', usecols=[0,1,2,3])        
Out[4]: 
array([[135.,  10., 125.,  10.],
       [230.,  16., 214.,  19.],
       [226.,  16., 210.,  19.],
       [231.,  16., 215.,  19.],
       [205.,  16., 189.,  17.]])
```

Or since you are going to split the array into two arrays anyways:

```
In [8]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',', usecols=[0,1,2,3], dtype=int)                                                               
Out[8]: 
array([[135,  10, 125,  10],
       [230,  16, 214,  19],
       [226,  16, 210,  19],
       [231,  16, 215,  19],
       [205,  16, 189,  17]])
In [9]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',', usecols=[4], dtype=None, encoding=None)                                                     
Out[9]: array(['1', 'not 1', '1', 'not 1', 'not 1'], dtype='<U5')
```

`dtype=None` lets it choose the appropriate dtype for each column.

```
In [10]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',', dtype=None, encoding=N
    ...: one)                                                                
Out[10]: 
array([(135, 10, 125, 10, '1'), (230, 16, 214, 19, 'not 1'),
       (226, 16, 210, 19, '1'), (231, 16, 215, 19, 'not 1'),
       (205, 16, 189, 17, 'not 1')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<i8'), ('f3', '<i8'), ('f4', '<U5')])
```

This is a structured array with a `field` for each column. And with fancier dtype specification:

```
In [13]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',', dtype='4i,U5', encoding=None)                                                             
Out[13]: 
array([([135,  10, 125,  10], '1'), ([230,  16, 214,  19], 'not 1'),
       ([226,  16, 210,  19], '1'), ([231,  16, 215,  19], 'not 1'),
       ([205,  16, 189,  17], 'not 1')],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4', (4,)), ('f1', '<U5')])
In [14]: _['f0']                                                             
Out[14]: 
array([[135,  10, 125,  10],
       [230,  16, 214,  19],
       [226,  16, 210,  19],
       [231,  16, 215,  19],
       [205,  16, 189,  17]], dtype=int32)
In [15]: __['f1']                                                            
Out[15]: array(['1', 'not 1', '1', 'not 1', 'not 1'], dtype='<U5')
```

So far I haven't tried to parse or convert those "not 1" strings.  We could construct a `converter` that would turn it into a number, such as 0.

If I define a converter function, like:

```
def foo(astr):
    if astr==b'not 1':
        astr = b'0'
    return int(astr)

In [31]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',', converters={4:foo}, dtype=int)                                                            
Out[31]: 
array([[135,  10, 125,  10,   1],
       [230,  16, 214,  19,   0],
       [226,  16, 210,  19,   1],
       [231,  16, 215,  19,   0],
       [205,  16, 189,  17,   0]])
```

Or if the converter returns a float:

```
def foo(astr):
    if astr==b'not 1':
        astr = b'0'
    return float(astr)
In [39]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',', converters={4:foo})   
Out[39]: 
array([[135.,  10., 125.,  10.,   1.],
       [230.,  16., 214.,  19.,   0.],
       [226.,  16., 210.,  19.,   1.],
       [231.,  16., 215.,  19.,   0.],
       [205.,  16., 189.,  17.,   0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the file with pandas:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(file, sep = ',')
numpydata = df.to_numpy() # will give a numpy array
```

Comment: tried this, returns this error----IndexError: too many indices for array----on the line----> 3 X=dataset[:100,2:4]

Comment: the result of that function is a dataframe, not a numpy array. you need to use differently the indexes